# When should a module be packaged into a versioned library?

Tags: design-patterns, architecture

When is it appropriate to take a module (or some unit of software) and convert it into a versioned package?

At my current company, we have a large monolithic application. Specifically, on the front-end we have many es6 modules that are either cross-cutting concerns, business logic, or helpful utilities. These modules are currently placed in a `shared/` directory where they get imported into specific pages as needed.

We are currently in the process of refactoring the front-end into many, smaller applications. My director has asked me to convert these modules into versioned npm packages that can be shared across the applications. This led me down the rabbit hole of wondering when is it, in general, appropriate to take a piece of code and share it as a versioned library.

I can think of potential harm it might cause by doing this: one module contains our form validation logic. Do we really want to allow some part of the application to use v1 of email validation logic, and some other part to use v2?

Comment: If it is a stand alone package it has commonly it's own versioning. If the version changes it is up to you to decide which depending components have to update their dependencies or not. This adds flexibility to the compatibility or release model when targeting customer requirements. So it is not about a "part of the application". The intent is not to mix the versions. It's about a consistent version of the application referencing one specific version. You would use either one or the other. Customer A gets a deployment version that depends on  v1 and customer B gets the latest v2 release.

Comment: This question is more appropriate for https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/